# (Google Sheets) Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1

Tags: google-sheets

im not sure how i exactly introduce this but im trying to data scraping on youtube but i keep getting errors in my code, im not a coder so any help would be very useful <3

```
function YouTubeScraper() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet()
  
  var search = YouTube.Search.list( 'id, snippet', {q:"coding" , maxresults : 50})

  var results = search.items.map ((item) => [item.snippet.title])

  var ids = results.map ((id) => id[0]).join(",")

  var stats = YouTube.Videos.list('statistics' , {id : ids})
  var videostats = stats.items.map ((item) => [item.statistics.viewCount])

activeSheet.getRange(2, 1 , results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results) 
activeSheet.getRange(2, 3, videostats.length, results[0].length).setValues(videostats) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either results or videostats arrays are empty. Use this:

```
if(results.length>0){
activeSheet.getRange(2, 1 , results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results) 
}

if(videostats.length>0){
activeSheet.getRange(2, 3, videostats.length, results[0].length).setValues(videostats) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, have a great day cause you've definitely brightened mine up.

Comment: thanks. If you don't mind. please mark the question as answered